# Como obtener de un listview (una cadena de uno o mas parametros) un parametro EN ANDROID

Tags: java, android

Quiero hacer un calculo en un listview que contiene dos parametros un string y un double. ¿Como podria obtener solo el double? Para ello tengo un spinner (con 5 parametros) que contiene una BD remota que obtengo con una entidad llamada Tbalimentos (getter y setter) y de acuerdo a lo que se seleccione me agrega el dato a un listview (obtiene dos parametros del valor del spinner seleccionado).

El objetivo es hacer una resta cuando se elimine el listview.

En el spinner obtengo un parametro numerico mediante un objeto json de la Tbalimentos que resto con un valor que obtengo de la pantalla anterior. Por cada seleccion del spinner se agrega a un listview pero cuando se elimina cualquier elemento de este hace una resta con este elemento eliminado. 
spdesayuno1 es es el spinner.

```
spdesayuno1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                if(position!=0){ 
                    Double calorias=frutasList.get(position-1).getCalorias();
                    String gastoT= getArguments()!=null ? getArguments().getString("gasto3"):"SIN DATOS";
                    double gastoT2 = Double.parseDouble(gastoT);//
                    System.out.println("PARAMETRO: " + gastoT2);
                    if(calconsumidas.equals(new Double(0))) {
                        calconsumidas = gastoT2 - calorias;
                    }                 
                    txtobjetivo.setText(gastoT2+"   -   ");
                    txtcalorias.setText(calorias+"    =    ");
                    txtcalconsumidas.setText(String.format("%.2f",calconsumidas));

                    //paso de parametros                   args.putString("gasto4",txtcalconsumidas.getText().toString());
                    fragment.setArguments(args);

                    listaview.add((frutasList.get(position - 1).getAlimento()));
                    System.out.println("ListView.size(): " + listaview.size());

                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
                    txtcalorias.setText("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
```

Aqui elimino y es donde esta el problema donde list es el listview:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int i, long l) {
                final int posicion=i;
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(FragmentoMenu.this.getActivity());
                dialogo1.setTitle("Importante");
                dialogo1.setMessage("¿ Elimina este alimento ?");
                dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
                dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {

                        //PROBLEMA
                        Double calorias = frutasList.get(position - 1).getCalorias();//si coloco esto me REGRESA el valor de los elementos del spinner

                        calconsumidas = calconsumidas + calorias;
                        txtcalconsumidas.setText(String.format("%.2f", calconsumidas));
                        //paso de parametros a colacion desayuno
                        args.putString("gasto2", txtcalconsumidas.getText().toString());
                        fragment.setArguments(args);

                        listaview.remove(posicion);
                        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });
                dialogo1.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    }
                });
                dialogo1.show();

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y muestra como llenas el spinner y el `ListView`

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio Angelica!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos y suerte!.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías dividir la información con `;` y utilizar `split` que te devuelve un arreglo de string, pero te separaría lo que está entre `;`. Por ejemplo:

```
String[] datos = itemValue.split(";");
```

me generará un arreglo de String a través de los datos que están entre `;`. En mi caso yo estoy haciendo proyectos universitarios y solo quiero sacar el id. en mi lista tengo los datos así:

```
1;Juan Carlos;Bodoque
```

Al utilizar `split` me separa el `1,Juan Carlos,Bodoque`, permitiéndome acceder al valor que necesito. Por el ejemplo el id entonces solo creo una variable:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(datos[0]);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, asi lo hice pero con String[] datos = itemValue.split("="); y pude separar el valor que queria, solo una duda, tengo concatenado un "="y " kcal" como podria decirle al  split que me separe cuando tenga ambos¿?

Comment: Yo creo haciendo 2 arreglos, ya que el split solo separa los datos por el texto dado ("kcal").